# Serializing Java ByteBuffer

Tags: java, gson

Not sure if this is even a valid question, but I wanted to know if we can serialize a ByteBuffer using gson?

I have an entry from DynamoDB which is exposed as a Map. The AttributeValue is of type B() (ByteBuffer).

I need to serialize the entire Map itself, but I wanted to know if serializing a ByteBuffer is even a right thing to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not serialize it as a byte array, or a blob?

Comment: I was just doing gson.toJson(Map<String, AttributeValue>);  I am guessing that serializes the byteBuffer?

Comment: It's probably the right thing to do but `Gson` doesn't support `ByteBuffer` out of the box, it'll interpret it as a POJO. Define your own `TypeAdapter` that Base64 encodes the `ByteBuffer`'s contents to a Base64 string.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Thank you for your response. I'll try that.